# Сортировка записей по рейтингу kk Star Ratings

Tags: wordpress, сортировка

Установил плагин kk Star Ratings всем устраивает, но не могу решить, как сделать сортировку записей по нему.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью другого плагина: WP-PostRatings

Добавляем в category.php

```
    if ($_GET['select'] == 'ratings_average') { $order = "&meta_key=ratings_average&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC"; $s5 = 'selected="selected"';}
if ($_GET['select'] == 'ratings_users7') { $order = "&meta_key=ratings_average&orderby=meta_value_num&order=ASC"; $s7 = 'selected="selected"';}
```

и вызываем:

```
<form method="get" class="sorting" id="order">
<select name="select" onchange='this.form.submit()' >
<option value="ratings_average"<?=$s5?>>Рейтинг</option>
<option value="ratings_users7"<?=$s7?>>Рейтинг меньше</option>
</select>
</form>
```

также:

```
    <?php global $query_string; // параметры базового запроса
query_posts($query_string.'&'.$order); // базовый запрос + свои параметры
?>
```